# ListPicker change borderbrush color when user tap

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, colors, toolkit, listpicker

I am using `toolkit:listpicker` finally a set background of `fullMode`, but now I can't change color of `borderBrush` when user are taped on `ListPicker`, I mean in default it set on `PhoneAccentBrush` color, even if I changed in App `((SolidColorBrush)Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"]).Color = ColorsPalete.LogoBlueColor;`

color of choosen listPicker is like real device accent

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ListPickerLearnMode" FullModeHeader="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.SettingsPageLearnBreak, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" FontStretch="Expanded">
 <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="36"/>                                     
   </DataTemplate>
 </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```